# How to stop calling a subroutine in fortran

Tags: fortran, call, exit, subroutine

I am attempting to call a subroutine within my code that looks like this;

```
           CALL RAYLEY(SIGR,AL2,Fwater,FNCR)
```

And when the code reaches this line, it gives me;

```
Program received signal SIGFPE: Floating-point exception - erroneous arithmetic operation.
```

I believe I know why this is occurring, because as this subroutine is running its calculations, after it iterates for a while, it ends up producing zeroes for 2 of the variables. This then results in the erroneous arithmetic expression. Is it possible in anyway to force the subroutine to stop being called when a variable becomes equal to 0, so that this can be avoided?

Comment: Please show your code. See [mcve]. Show how you call the subroutine and probably also the code of the subroutine. Show where those two variables are.

Comment: A lot depends on the variable.  If it is an integer, you can easily check for zero with an if statement.  If it is real, then you will probably need a range check. Sometimes reals are near zero but not exactly zero.  Will the code fall over if the variable value is -1E-38?